# How does SimpleITK is able to differentiate with a different color when doing image registration

Tags: image, image-registration, simpleitk

I am working on a simpleITK Image Registration method using Regular gradient descent method. I was interested to know how does the simpleITK able to highlight differences between the Fixed image and Moving images.

For example below is one of the tutorials which shows different coloring with Pink & green colors:
Fixed Image - Red
Moving Image - Green

http://kevin-keraudren.blogspot.in/2014/12/medical-image-analysis-ipython-tutorials.html

*Image Courtesy - Kevin Keraudren.*

Comment: Is your question about how simpleITK computes the objective function used to optimize the registration (the difference between corresponding pixels in the fixed and moving image) or do you want to know how the images that are shown in the tutorial which are just for demonstration purposes are produced?

Comment: I want to know how simpleITK is able to highlight the pixel differences which is as a result of the Registration process. Like as we can see in the example that fixed image is in Red / pink color and moving image is in the green color. And how is it able to show the fixed image in red / pink color and similarly green color for the moving image.